# Example of working Wildfly 9 domain.xml cluster config using TCP

Tags: tcp, wildfly

We are constantly struggling with the configuration of Wildfly server (currently version 9.0.1.Final) running in cluster and using TCP. There is a plenty of examples that use UDP, however in many hosting environments TCP is the only option and there is a lack of documentation for such a configuration.

Particularly, we have problems to connect the nodes into the cluster. How specificaly HornetQ should be set up?

Is there someone using Wildfly (preferably 9) in cluster on TCP and could share their **domain.xml**? Many thanks in advance.